# Destroy a session with ajax to avoid exiting page

Tags: php, wordpress, session-variables, session-state

When a user visits a search result page, the user needs to click "clear search filters" which redirects the user to the search page. The session is cleared upon this action.

I'm looking for a way to destroy the session via ajax - so that the user can make use of the filter options directly on the search results page (without having to go back to the search page).

This the code I have now:

```
<?php session_start(); if($_GET['action']=='reset') {
  session_destroy();
  wp_redirect( 'http://website.com/search' ); exit;  
} else { 
  if(!is_page(4097))  { 
  session_destroy(); } 
} ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
</head>


<body>
<?php if(!is_page(4097)) { ?>
<form name="search-form" method="post" action="<?php echo get_permalink(4097);?>">
    <select name="one">
       <?php echo $form_options_one; ?>
    </select>
    <select name="two">
       <?php echo $form_options_two; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<?php }?>

<div id="container">
```

search_and_results.php code is below:

```
<?php 
session_start();
get_header();
if($_GET['action']=='reset'){
session_destroy();
wp_redirect( get_permalink(get_the_ID()) ); exit; 
}?>

    <div id="content">  

            <?php if(!isset($_POST['submit']) && (!isset($_SESSION['one'])) && (!isset($_SESSION['two']))) { ?>
            <form name="search-form" method="post" action="<?php echo get_permalink(4097);?>">
                <select name="one">
                   <?php echo $form_options_one; ?>
                </select>
                <select name="two">
                   <?php echo $form_options_two; ?>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
            </form>


            <?php } else {          
                $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                $the_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
                <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                  <!-- the loop -->
                  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php $author_data= get_userdata($post->post_author); $author_meta= get_user_meta($post->post_author); ?>
                    <?php if(($author_data->roles[0]=='editor') || ($author_data->roles[0]=='contributor') || ($author_data->roles[0]=='subscriber') ) { ?>
                    // only get posts from editors, contributors, and subscribers

                            <!--post stuff here-->

                    <?php }?>           
                  <?php endwhile; ?> <!-- end of the loop -->

                  <!-- pagination here -->
                <?php if($the_query->max_num_pages==1) {
                    session_destroy();
                }?>

                <?php  if ( $the_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>

                <div class="main_navigation">
                    <?php
                    // usage with max_num_pages
                    next_posts_link( 'Next Page &raquo;', $the_query->max_num_pages );
                    previous_posts_link( '&laquo; Previous Page' );
                    ?>
                </div>

                <?php endif; ?>

                  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                <?php else:  ?>
                  <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>


            <div class="back-to-form clearfix">
                <a href="<?php echo home_url('/') ?>?action=reset" class="clear_filter button">< Clear search filters</a>
            </div>
                <?php  } ?>

</div><!-- end content id -->
 </div><!--container-->
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible given the structure above? Thanks so much

Comment: `session_regenerate_id(TRUE)` - (http://docs.php.net/session_regenerate_id)[http://docs.php.net/session_regenerate_id]

Comment: Are you using wordpress i guess `wp_redirect()` is wp's function ?

Comment: Yes, @dianuj - exactly - using wordpress

Answer (score 1):

from what i understand, you need to change the way you structure your page to do this.
first create an external page to make the ajax call and handle the session in that external page. for example, every time this external page loads your session sets to false like this

```
external-page.php
<?php
$_SESSION['searchfilters']=0;
//this will set to 0 any time this page is run by ajax or original url.
?>
```

second if you want load the search page without user having to leave  the page, make another call by jquery or ajax that loads your search page into a designated div or some html tag.

your ajax function would be something like this

```
        $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                //data:'',
                url:"http://www.yourdomain.com/external-page.php",//this will clear the session values to 0.
                success: function(data){ 
                    //here you reload your search page into designated div with an id or class then user do not have to leave the page.




                }, //end of success
                error: function(){
                    //display any error message here
                    }// end of error
            });
```

hope that helps you find your path.

A reminder, Do not use session_destroy(), if you are having users with accounts on your site, this will kill all the existing sessions for the current user and log them out.

Comment: In the header.php BEFORE the doctype I have the above code. I think my problem is that the search page is the same as the search results page - the session and session output is all in one file. Is this a problem? `<?php session_start(); get_header(); if($_GET['action']=='reset'){ session_destroy(); wp_redirect( get_permalink(get_the_ID()) ); exit; }?>` is at the TOP of the search results/search page, but the page uses conditionals - ie, if(!isset($_POST['submit']) - to differentiate between search page or search results page. Will the method you referenced above still work in this instance?

Comment: i cannot possibly guide you on this properly unless i see the code, but i think you should change the skeleton of this search page. if you will use any javascript based code for this particular page, you can use one or more external php pages to run via jquery or ajax calls. wherever your search page is located keep it simple and create one or two external pages to make ajax/jquery calls to and get the data from those pages, place them into a div on your search page. i believe that will handle all of it.

Comment: thanks so much for your guidance. I've edited my question above to include all code. I think you're right - my best bet is to change the skeleton of the search page. The idea is to have the form on the search page too - and as you can see from the code above, it's excluded from the page above because the session doesn't destroy until you leave the page.

Comment: Re: your added comment - "Do not use session_destroy(), if you are having users with accounts on your site, this will kill all the existing sessions for the current user and log them out." can you elaborate - this has not kicked me out as a current user - and I have session_destroy() many times. Maybe a Wordpress thing? What is another way around this - do you know? (an alternative for session_destroy())